why does ubuntu 24.04lts crash to my login screen?
I'll be browsing with FireFox and suddenly the machine locks-up (conky freezes, mouse freezes, keyboard non-responsive, etc.) , but the hard drive light is blinking away furiously, then it crashes to a blank screen and after a few minutes goes to my login screen, losing all my work... why?
btw - posting boot.log not useful, so...

Among other possible reasons, insufficient RAM. Your Ubuntu system has tools to monitor RAM usage.

If you have such issues, take a look at the journal for the previous boot, save it and post. Asking in a low-effort way like this will not yield solutions or people willing to look into it.

posted boot.log ~ noticed that just before it crashed/logout today, I paused the streaming video but noticed the processor use was very high for no apparent reason, for nothing streaming - ram is only about 2/3 used so not ram/swap file issue.
Changed update for security from 'download and install immediately' to just display immediately - may be what's overloading the machine and dumping me out?

Changed update for security from 'download and install immediately' to just 'display immediately' - afterwards suddenly, a security update popped-up - it was trying to download 196Mb, install, and then need to reboot to finish ~ something like that is what's overloading the machine and dumping me out in a panic attack.
My 2Gb Ram was not affected (still had plenty and swapfile very small), but the 2 gig dual core processor was just getting jammed - I could see Conky display activity where processor was maxed yet no streaming or anything heavy on firefox was going on.
Well, the main thing is the dumping me to login has stopped - still don't understand the mechanics of it freezing up and instead of just staying locked-up it logs out! Better than going to reboot I guess...
Now I get a notice to update while browsing or streaming which I can minimize the notice and let it get taken care of next boot up :-D
